# Why do I get wrong result

Tags: java, arraylist

I am doing Leetcode 118 Pascal's Triangle and my code is as below. The testcase is five. I should get

```
[[1],[1,1],[1,2,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,4,6,4,1]].
```

However, my output is

```
[[1,4,6,4,1],[1,4,6,4,1],[1,4,6,4,1],[1,4,6,4,1],[1,4,6,4,1]]
```

I know that the line with comments was not right. But can anyone let me know why I can't just add row to the result? Thanks!

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> generate(int numRows) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList();
        List<Integer> row = new ArrayList();
        for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++ ){
            row.add(0,1);
            for(int j = 1; j < row.size()-1; j++){
                row.set(j, row.get(j) + row.get(j+1));
            }
            result.add(row); // this line should be result.add(new ArrayList(row));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `result` list is a list of references to `row`. The first time you iterate, `row` refers to an array like `[1]`. As you keep going through the iterations, you're continuously dereferencing and referencing the variable row.
Since result is essentially [row ,row , row, row ... and so on], you're seeing the result you see here. You'll get the same object as the same block of memory is being referenced and you're overwriting it each time.

On the other hand, `new ArrayList(row)` actually creates a new block of memory with duplicated data from `row` - hence this works.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation!